# How to find the smallest values of list of matrices by column

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of matrices. Suppose further that I would like to find the smallest value across each value of the matrices. For example,

```
y <- c(3,2,4,5,6, 4,5,5,6,7)
x[lower.tri(x,diag=F)] <- y
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    3    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    6    0    0    0
[4,]    4    4    5    0    0
[5,]    5    5    6    7    0



k <- c(1,4,5,2,5,-4,4,4,4,5)
z[lower.tri(z,diag=F)] <- k
> z
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    4    5    0    0    0
[4,]    5   -4    4    0    0
[5,]    2    4    4    5    0



 d <- list(k, x)
```

**The expected output:**

```
dd <– matrix(0,5,5)
    dd
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    5    0    0    0
[4,]    4   -4    4    0    0
[5,]    2    4    4    5    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `pmin` to get the corresponding min value for each element across the `list`

```
do.call(pmin, d)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    2    5    0    0    0
#[4,]    4   -4    4    0    0
#[5,]    2    4    4    5    0
```

#### data

```
d <- list(z, x)
```