# R: how to calculate element-wise arg-min from a list of matrices?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of matrices. Suppose further I have found the smallest values by the column.
[Here is my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544519/how-to-find-the-smallest-values-of-list-of-matrices-by-column)

I really need to know from which matrix each smallest value is selected. My original function is very complicated. Therefore, I provided a simple example. I have one idea and really do not know to implement it correctly in R.

My idea is:

Suppose that `[i,j]` is the elements of the matrix. Then,

```
if(d[[1]][i,j] < d[[2]][i,j]){
d[[1]][i,j] <– "x"
}else { d[[2]][i,j] <– "z"}
```

**So, I would like to sign the name of the matrix that corresponds to each smallest value. Then, store the names in a separate matrix. So, then I can see the values in one matrix and their corresponding names (from where they come from) in another matrix**

For example,

```
y <- c(3,2,4,5,6, 4,5,5,6,7)
x[lower.tri(x,diag=F)] <- y
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    3    0    0    0    0
[3,]    2    6    0    0    0
[4,]    4    4    5    0    0
[5,]    5    5    6    7    0



k <- c(1,4,5,2,5,-4,4,4,4,5)
z[lower.tri(z,diag=F)] <- k
> z
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    4    5    0    0    0
[4,]    5   -4    4    0    0
[5,]    2    4    4    5    0



 d <- list(z, x)
```

Then:

```
do.call(pmin, d) (answered by @akrun)
```

Then, I will only get the matrix with smallest values. I would like to know where each value is come from?

Any idea or help, please?

Comment: Please include x and z in your question (maybe with `dput`) so your question has a reproducible example.

Comment: @lmo thank you for your comment. They are already there.

Comment: Neither x nor z is defined in this question in a reproducible manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Map` and `do.call` to create your own functions that will be applied element-wise to a list of inputs,
in your case a list of matrices.

```
pwhich.min <- function(...) {
  which.min(c(...)) # which.min takes a single vector as input
}

di <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(list(f = pwhich.min), d)))
dim(di) <- dim(x) # take dimension from one of the inputs
di

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    2    1    1    1
[4,]    1    2    2    1    1
[5,]    2    2    2    2    1
```

EDIT:

To elaborate,
you could do something like `Map(f = min, z, x)` to apply `min` to each pair of values in `z` and `x`,
although in that case `min` already supports arbitrary amount of inputs through an ellipsis (`...`).

By contrast,
`which.min` only takes a single vector as input,
so you need a wrapper with an ellipsis that combines all values into a vector
(`pwhich.min` above).

Since you may want to have more than two matrices,
you can put them all in a list,
and use `do.call` to put each element in the list as a parameter to the function you specify in `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Or another option would be to convert it to a 3D array and use `apply` with `which.min`

```
apply(array(unlist(d), c(5, 5, 2)), c(1, 2), which.min)
```

---

Or with `pmap` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
pmap_int(d, ~ which.min(c(...))) %>%
       array(., dim(x))
```